# Is this bad design for a Shape interface?

Tags: design, object-oriented, code-smell, interfaces, composition

I'm creating a vector editing program in C++, and I need a Shape interface which other concrete classes will implement. There is a requirement that *no implementation inheritance* is allowed. The design doc says that if you need polymorphism, **use interfaces**. If you need code reuse, **use composition**.

The **Shape** interface is:

```
class Shape
{
  public:

   virtual void get_name()=0;
   virtual void set_name()=0;
   virtual void get_linewidth()=0;
   virtual void set_linewidth()=0;

   ...
   ...about 20 other getters/setters
   ...

   virtual void draw()=0;
   virtual int area()=0;
   virtual void rotate(int angle)=0;

}
```

The Circle class:

```
class Circle: public Shape
{
  string name;
  int line_width;
  int angle_of_rotation;
  int radius;
public:
  string get_name(){ return name; }
  string set_name(string name){ this->name=name; }
  ...
  ...about 20 other getters/setters
  ...

  int area()
  {
    return PI*pow(this->radius,2);
  }

}
```

I have no problem with this, except common properties have to be **repeated for each type of shape**! This is solved using inheritance, but I am **not allowed to use that**.

So, I create a **ShapeProperties** class

```
class ShapeProperties
{
  string name;
  int line_width;
  int angle_of_rotation;

public:

  string get_name(){ return name; }
  string set_name(string name){ this->name=name; }

  ...
  ...about 20 other getters/setters
  ...

}
```

and a properties() method for the interface:

```
virtual ShapeProperties* properties()=0;
```

A user would then do:

```
Shape *shape = new Circle();
shape->properties()->set_name("my shape");
shape->properties()->set_line_width(4);
int area = shape->area();
```

**My question:** Is this good design? Is this bad design? Are there any obvious problems? How could it be made better?

Comment: No inheritance is a stupid thing to do. Even terrible languages like Java allow single inheritance.

Comment: That's the requirement. And it's not stupid, considering the fact that it is usually abused. Of course, there are many arguments on both sides.

Comment: Usually abused? Right. So because *other people* de-reference NULL on occasion, we should ban pointers in *all* cases for *all* people? That's a bad argument. The use, or not, of a given feature should be considered on a case by case basis, and the fact that it *can* be mis-used is no excuse for not using it when it is totally appropriate.

Comment: I had a feeling you were going to say that! However, inheritance is *commonly* misused, especially with junior programmers (there are many juniors on the team).

Comment: And that's a reason why the non-juniours shouldn't use it because....? As I previously stated, just because it *can* be mis-used is no reason to ban it, only to pay attention before you use it. As you can see in the problem in the question, it's more than possible to mis-use interface inheritance just as much. Oh, and it's also perfectly possible to mis-use dogma.

Comment: And that's a reason why the non-juniours shouldn't use it because....there is a high change of misuse. And this 'dogma' of disallowing implementation inheritance is advocated by some respected persons. Some programming languages consider it such as plague as to not even allow it, period.

Comment: OK. You are faced with a problem which would clearly be best solved by implementation inheritance. Your only solution is a filthy hack. You only have two choices. One: Use filthy hack and create a bad program. Two: Look at the evidence in front of your face and consider the possibility that those respected persons made a mistake. If you want a good program, pick #2. If you'd rather lick boots, pick #1. Also, there are billions of bad languages, and having a language which does not have a feature means absolutely nothing whatsoever. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_authority

Comment: Circle class should have a constructor with some parameters...

Comment: Is this a case of using C++ to imitate a style object-oriented C programming?  Odd.

Comment: @DeadMG: For what it's worth, the Common Object Model which preceded .NET had interfaces but not inheritance.  Having only interfaces does simplify the run-time environment somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad design because you have implemented a subclass for something that isn't a genuine subclass. A Circle is simply one example of a FunctionalShape, as opposed to a VertexShape. Examples of FunctionalShapes are circles, and also ellipses, and similar things. The function used to generate the shape is just data, and it's a bad idea to create different subclasses to represent different things which are just data.

What your code demonstrates is that the restriction to an interface is pointless, because your logic can be trivially reduced to not requiring a dynamic dispatch. Most of it could just be even a public member variable. Technically, you haven't used implementation inheritance, but in reality, you have, you've just coded it in a slightly different fashion.

The reality is that without using implementation inheritance, there is no way in C++ to make this code usable. There's a reason that that language feature exists and it's because not having it is dumb, and pointless, and makes your life very hard for no valid reason whatsoever.

Composition can re-use logic. It can't re-use class *description*, which is the part that you're endlessly (and pointlessly) repeating. There is no solution within your given constraints.

Comment: It is 'just data' for this simplified example. I will have to do validation on it e.g. ensure that the Shape's name has a certain length, ensure that line_width is not more than 10. So, it certainly is *not a POD* which you are implying!

Comment: @illmath: The need to factor out a couple of setters is way different to factoring out the existence of the variables and factoring out *all* the getters and *all* the setters.

Comment: So how would you design this code "right", then?

Answer (score 0):

`shape->properties()->set_name("my shape");`

This is called train wreck, therefore it is better to avoid, because the method that needs to call `properties()` and then `set_name()` needs to know too much.
Unless the `shape` is a data structure, and in your case doesn't seems to be.

---

If you must use method to get properties, then make them data structure (without any methods, and with all public member variables), and return const reference :

```
const ShapeProperties& properties() const
```

then the properties looks like :

```
struct ShapeProperties
{
  std::string name;
  int line_width;
  int angle_of_rotation;
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I mean no implementation inheritance. Edited the question.

Comment: @illmath Ok, hope the answer now makes more sense

Comment: I'll look into that. One problem that comes to mind: what if there needs to be some validation in the future e.g. the name has to be *at least* 8 characters long? For this reason, I kept it as a method set_name(string).